# Binding to UserControl DataContext: update ContentTemplateSelector when some properties change

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `UserControl`, in which the key visual element is presented like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
     ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MStatusDisplaySelector}" />
```

The `DataContext` of this element (i.e. the binding target) is the `UserControl` itself. The `MStatusDisplaySelector` is a complex selector, and it selects a `DataTemplate` based on several properties of this `UserControl` (which are all simple `DependencyProperty`).

The problem is, when any of these properties change, a different template may need to be selected, and I want to update the `ContentPresenter`. This obviously doesn't happen. What is the best way to work around this?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid implementing change callbacks in every involved property. Not only this is too verbose, but the template selector may need to use a different set of properties later on, and maintaining this in sync is not handy. However, it is probably OK to update the template on *any* property change.

P.S. Assume that the `MStatusDisplaySelector` logics is too complicated to be reduced to a traditional style selector with `Style.Triggers`. I'd like it to stay in code-behind.

Comment: Sounds like a style trigger with setters that change the template, or else a template selector. Seems a bit unusual to be changing the whole template on property changes (usually you'd show or hide elements of the template based on properties, and change templates only when the runtime type of ContentControl.DataContext changes), but without more detail I really can't judge.

Comment: Well, @Ed, I realise it may not be exactly WPF-like (I'm only learning), but as I said, `MStatusDisplaySelector` is not trivial and I don't see how I could implement it in xaml (or rather, it will be extremely verbose). For example, one of the properties is a complex bitwise pattern, based on which I may need to display an image, or a grid of images, or text, or hide it altogether. Writing such thing in code-behind is easy, but not so in xaml.

Comment: You could do that logic in a value converter, I guess. Certainly you wouldn't try to write that logic in XAML. Anyway it sounds like you thought this through.

Comment: Actually, seeing the trouble you're having getting the template to reapply, if you can't get that to work, some fallback ideas: Copy your template selector logic to a value converter and use it in a series of DataTriggers in one template to show/hide elements, or maybe in a Style to set ContentTemplate. Or write a property that returns the template, put the logic in there, bind ContentTemplate to that, and raise PropertyChanged for it as needed when properties change. When theologically pure XAML fails, commit heresy.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your UserControl code :

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue != null && e.Property.ToString() == "Title")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Property.ToString() + " > " + e.OldValue.ToString() + " : " + e.NewValue.ToString());
            /* You can call your TemplateSelector method here, or put some code here */
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
```

In this overridden method you can inspect the `Property` which is making this method getting called, and take proper action accordingly.

Comment: This way I can detect a change. This is indeed the easiest way. But the main question is: what action should I take? How do I nudge my `ContentPresenter` to refresh its template? I could, probably, remove the `ContentTemplateSelector` declaration and assign `ContentTemplate` from code in this handler... But this looks even more un-WPF to me...

Comment: @Zeus Its unclear about refreshing the template. Whenever the property bound to `Content ` changes `Binding` will refresh the `Content` which in turn will call the `TemplateSelector`. So, you can change the `ViewModel:bound-property` in the `OnPropertyChanged` method which in turn will refresh `Content`.

Comment: But the binding target is the `UserControl` itself. In other words, effectively `.Content = this` (I didn't assign a `Name` in my original code above). If I force this assignment in the `OnPropertyChanged`, it won't do anything because the object itself didn't change. Only some of its properties did.

Comment: Use `UpdateTarget()` method of `BindingExpression` class. Get the `BindingExpression` instance of your `ContentControl` using `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression`. If this doesn't work for you, then what I originally suggested will best best.

Comment: No, I've tried that (`cpStatus.GetBindingExpression(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();` where `cpStatus` is the name of my `ContentPresenter`) and it doesn't work (even for explicit mode etc.). Nevertheless, the problems is solvable; but I'm wondering if there is a standard approach for such things - being new, I can easily miss something trivial.

Comment: @Zeus You can re-assign the binding by first setting it to null, then reassigning it in code. This will refresh everything, but anyhow calling your template-selector function is still very easy way. It's getting called anyhow by Binding mechanism right now.